# After exporting fusion chart save button is trunacted in IE 8 with other browser it works fine

Tags: fusioncharts

We are using fusion charts in appln. When we click upon export to PDF/jpeg/png a progress bar is displayed untill the exported chart is reday to be saved. When it gets ready a save button from flash file is displayed.After clicking this save button, a save as window opens up.

Only in IE browser flash save button is truncated or not visible.
While debugging through developers tool the code for it is present.
FCExporter.swf path is also correct.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the following:

1. Whether you are not using any CSS (like height:100% etc.) which is truncating the export component
2. Whether the SWF is rendered in the browser